# Building an F# Xamarin project on a TeamCity Linux agent: Could not import Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.FSharp.targets

Tags: linux, xamarin, f#, teamcity, monodevelop

I've got MonoDevelop installed on my TeamCity agent. I am trying to build an F# Xamarin project on the agent, but I'm getting this error:

> /opt/buildagent/work/f12265fda07473c1/src/MyProject/MyProject.fsproj
>   could not import
>   "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.FSharp.targets"

I was under the impression that MonoDevelop already supported Xamarin's F# bindings.

Is there anything else I need to install on my agent?

Comment: Are all of the Xamarin Android pre-requisites available? I’ve seen similar build failures when certain libraries were missing.